# Translate unsigned char *buf=NULL to Pascal?

Tags: c++, delphi, char, translate, pchar

I'm working in Borland Delphi, and i have a few lines code in Borland C++ Builder. I would like to translate these lines into Delphi source.

```
unsigned char *buf=NULL;
buf=new unsigned char[SPS*2];
for (i=0; i<SPS*2; i++)
   buf[i]=2;
```

...
....

```
answers=buf[2];
```

I would like to assign a PCHar value with this buf;

```
a:PCHar;
a:=buf.
```

Comment: 1) `unsigned char` = `Byte`, not `Char` (blame Ritchie for that), 2) `new` can be translated to `GetMem(<integral sizeof>)` or with intermediate type which declares size 3) for loop is straightforward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
var
  buf: array of AnsiChar;
  a: PAnsiChar;
...
SetLength(buf, SPS*2);
FillChar(buf[0], Length(buf), 2);
a := @buf[0];
```

No idea what `answers` is, but, assuming it is a `char` in your C++ code then you would write it like this:

```
var
  answers: AnsiChar;
...
answers := buf[2];
```

Comment: can i use instead of array of AnsiChar into array of Byte?

Comment: They are pretty much interchangeable. But if you want to treat as a `PAnsiChar` then you'd need a cast. Nothing much to be gained by using `Byte` rather than `AnsiChar` I suspect.

Comment: dynamic array only makes things worse, `PChar^` and `PByte^` are arrays already (BTW, this is C++, not C)

Comment: @premature What are you talking about? What's wrong with dynamic arrays? They are an excellent match to C++ new[]. Where you propose getting the buffer from?

Answer (score 6):

In fact, in:

```
unsigned char *buf=NULL;
buf=new unsigned char[SPS*2];
```

The first assignment `*buf=NULL` can be translated as `buf := nil` but it is pure dead code, since `buf` pointer content is immediately overwritten by the `new` function.

So your C code may be translated as such:

```
var buf: PAnsiChar;
    i: integer;
begin
  Getmem(buf,SPS*2);
  for i := 0 to SPS*2-1 do
    buf[i] := #2;
...
  Freemem(buf);
end;
```

A more Delphi-idiomatic version may be:

```
var buf: array of AnsiChar;
    i: integer;
begin
  SetLength(buf,SPS*2);
  for i := 0 to high(buf) do
    buf[i] := #2;
  ...
  // no need to free buf[] memory (it is done by the compiler)
end;
```

or directly:

```
var buf: array of AnsiChar;
    i: integer;
begin
  SetLength(buf,SPS*2);
  fillchar(buf[0],SPS*2,2);
  ...
  // no need to free buf[] memory (it is done by the compiler)
end;
```